# Proper way to install a public github repo to use in Google Colab?

Tags: python, github, pip, google-colaboratory

I have a public Github repository -- and I'd like to pip install it in my Google Colab Python notebook and use some of the functions in its .py file.

This is how I'm trying to install it:

`!pip install git+http://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin#egg=inkblottin`

This is the error I'm getting:

`Collecting inkblottin
  Cloning http://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin to /tmp/pip-install-4l26ktdy/inkblottin
  Running command git clone -q http://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin /tmp/pip-install-4l26ktdy/inkblottin
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

What am I missing here? Is it an issue with my repo or with my Colab code?

Comment: Can you add the log to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install the package with the command

```
pip install 'git+http://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin#egg=inkblottin'
```

locally and got the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-54bd678379cf43d6/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/
Complete output (7 lines):
running egg_info
creating /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info/inkblottin.egg-info
writing /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info/inkblottin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info/inkblottin.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info/inkblottin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-4lmCa8/inkblottin/pip-egg-info/inkblottin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
error: package directory 'inkblottin' does not exist
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is a bug in the package: its `setup.py` [tries to install package `inkblottin`](https://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin/blob/5c376dd5c56d77783446d9bb0c71fdb62c39f085/setup.py#L10) but [the distribution](https://github.com/benmercerdev/inkblottin/tree/583106e0d8a0e4b907260b418a4a90d053479c79) doesn't have such a package, it only has `inkblot`. Please fix your `setup.py` or rename the top-level package.